# how to use xmlhttprequest object's post method for sending data

Tags: javascript, mootools, xmlhttprequest

I want to send data that is in a java script variable to the server.the variable is in a method that is executing when I click a button on the web site.here is the code written in that method for sending data.

```
    var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("POST","new_map.php",true);
xmlhttp.send(cur_entry_string);
```

and here is code written in new_map.php file for getting data.here cur_entry_string is the variable that is holding that data.

$massage = $_POST[cur_entry_string];

but this is not working..:(...I am using eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should have a look at an AJAX tutorial http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp and if that is not what you want to do you can also look into JSON

Comment: Read the rest of the web page and follow the links on the left

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually generate a valid query string. A query string in POST looks the same as a GET string.

Something like this should work:

```
xmlhttp.send('cur_entry_string=' + cur_entry_string);
```

I would recommend using a library such as jQuery for using Ajax, as it simplifies the process a lot so you don't need to do error prone things like these query string things yourself.

---

ps. note that you should enclose array string indices in quotes when using PHP:

```
$_POST['cur_entry_string']
```

Comment: it is not working even after setting query string that you gave.is there any other reason to happen this?thank you for your info.

Comment: I can't use jquery because web site is building with mootools.so it is conflict to add jquery.

Comment: Have you tried using Mootools' ajax functionality? See: http://mootools.net/docs/core/Request/Request